# Get string data from specific table of local database

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get data from my local database that is present in my app project.

This is the code:

```
private void HW_Info()
    {
        const string strConnectionString = @"appdata:/WInfoAppDevicesDB.sdf";
        using (DeviceDataContext db = new DeviceDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            var projectName = from m in db.Devices
                                 where m.ProductName == deviceName
                                 select m;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I didn't obtain values of my table, but a string of SQL query, and I don't know which table app will choose (there are three tables with same columns type).

(I'm newbie with Linq-to-SQL because I studied only SQL, so I apologize for my lack of preparation about it)

Comment: Do you mean you see SQL string in the debugger?

Comment: No, I tried to show directly on my app in a Textblock...I see only SQL query in traditional form (SELECT... FROM... WHERE...), but there isn't any name of table which it try to retrieve data...

Comment: Your query isn't retrieving table names. It's retrieving rows in Devices table. Is that what you are trying to do? See my answer, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve data from a specific table. Example: I have table named HTC and I want to take a row of a specific device model (as you see, I used "where m.ProductName == deviceName" ), but I didn't retrieve anything else that SQL query (now I observe that program give me a System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException...maybe is a corrupted Database?)

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.dll: {"Unspecified error [ \\Applications\\Install\\BE7C7F65-B398-4696-ADFF-6A4D65DEB5CD\\Install\\WInfoAppDevicesDB.sdf ]"}; Native Error: 25046

Comment: I believe error 25046 means file not found. Are you sure connection string is correct?

Comment: Yes, I search before where it is located in my app when is compiled...and my app found it, because I tried to insert a messagebox to show the result of db.DatabaseExists() and return true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet that you have provided in the question, you are querying the "Devices" table.

Based on your comments, it seems like 'Devices' table is not available in the database that you are using.

In case you want to select records from "HTC" table, change the linq query as below

```
var projectName = from m in db.HTC
                  where m.ProductName == 'deviceName'
                  select m;
```

The equivalent SQL query for the above linq query is as below

```
SELECT * FROM HTC m WHERE m.ProductName = 'deviceName';
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Mmm the problem is (and I now tried) that I can't put the name HTC directly in the code because compiler think is a variable that I didn't defined, and if I put it as string format ("HTC"), it gives me error as wrong code, because of implicit conversion to string from a Table variable.

Comment: It seems like you haven't updated the entity data model to match with the latest schema. Please try updating the data model to add the missing tables before trying the solution that I have provided above.